# Change footer for different pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On my mobile site, I have a footer with a button of "back" (using Jquery Mobile) - I am trying to figure out how to remove the button for the home page (so it just shows the footer with no button), but have the button show up on sub-pages.  Basically, one footer for the home page, and one footer for all the sub-pages.  But since I only have one footer.php file, I'm not sure how to alter code (or even what to put) to have two different footers.  I originally asked over at the Jquery Mobile form, but they said this is a PHP question..so I'm here.

Here is my footer code:

```
</div><!-- data role content-->
     <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer">
    <h3>
        Premier IT Consulting
    </h3>
    <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="back"    
data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
        Back</a>
</div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</div><!-- data role content-->
</body>
</html>
```

In the Wordpress template I'm using, the index.php and page.php are making calls to the footer.php - hence, they are showing the same footer on every page (home page and all sub-pages).  I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  If I remove the HTML from the footer, it won't show on any page.

Just FYI.  I'm using wordpress and instead of  hosting the .js and .css files on my site, I'm using this in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-
1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try test if it is homepage for your button. For example:

```
 <?php if (!is_home() ) : ?>
 <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="back"    
 data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.  That snipet of code you included - does this make the button hidden from the home page, but shows the button on all other pages?  Sorry, I just don't understand that PHP code.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For common cases that code should hide button from home page, but show on all other pages.

Comment: Thanks again Vladimir.  The code you provided did not work - well, the button works, but the button still shows on the home page and all sub-pages.  You can see it here:  [link](http://s3cc.net/mobile)

Comment: Seems it is not regular homepage -  that can be reason why code is not working. Try add in footer next code and write here what you will see at the bottom of page after that change.


    `<?php echo "<br>This is pagename: " . basename(get_permalink()) . "<br>"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

use is_front_page() to make sure you are on the home page:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>
<a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
 <?php endif; ?>
```